# Category and tag with same name

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, tags

IN my blog, if I have a category and tag with the same name, it will make the tag have a number in the URI.

Example:

**category/php**

**tags/php-2**

Is there anyway to make my tags with the same name as an existing category, to not append a number to the end of them for my links?

Comment: No, but I wish there was.

Comment: More importantly: *why do you need both a Category and a Post Tag to have the same term*? Perhaps the best solution would be to re-think your post categorization/tagging scheme a bit, such that you eliminate the need to use the same term as both a Category and a Post Tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags and Categories use the same system, So that is not possible. It will not hurt SEO in any way to use php-2, it is just visually displeasing.